# wininet or winhttp, which is preferred for POST requests

Tags: c++, c, winapi, wininet, winhttp

I was going through the MSDN page comparing WinInet and WinHttp. Seems as though WinInet has more functionality than WinHttp. The MSDN page is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh227297(v=vs.85).aspx). Under what circumstances would one choose WinHttp over WinInet?

Considering that WinInet has HttpSendRequest that can be used to POST data and WinHttp also has WinHttpSendRequest. What would be the advantages of taking WinHttp over WinInet? Is there a difference in how the data is posted using WinHttp and WinInet?

In addition, if some examples of POSTing requests with both WinHttp and WinInet would help, some small sample codes.

**EDIT 3 WIRESHARK SCREENSHOT**
[image]

**EDIT 2** I finally managed to get a HTTP_STATUS_CODE from the app and it's 200 OK but the problem comes when sending the post data, it is sent but the parameters aren't set. I tried implementing this code on the PHP end.

```
<?php

    $fp = fopen("data.txt", "a");
    fwrite($fp, "ID = " . $_POST['id']);
    fclose($fp);

?>
```

the file is created as soon as the app runs but the ID parameter is not set, it writes to the file
"ID = " and no more. the 10 is not being passed through, no idea why

Thank You.

**EDIT: Link to the example I tried to use.**
[HttpSendRequest to POST form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713898/httpsendrequest-to-post-fom-data)

Comment: meh, when the library authors start to confuse themselves, I go to libcurl.

Comment: i know of libcurl but i don't want to use any libraries @gbjbaanb :), thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Asking for library recommendations on SO is not really allowed; having said that, I just learned about [Casablanca](http://casablanca.codeplex.com) which looks really neat and is probably worth considering.

Answer (score 4):

Actually MSDN has a good page on [WinHTTP vs. WinINet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh227297(v=vs.85).aspx), stating:

> With a few exceptions, WinINet is a superset of WinHTTP. When selecting between the two, you should use WinINet, unless you plan to run within a service or service-like process that requires impersonation and session isolation.

Comment: I got that but i read in a post on a another website that one should use WinHttp for POST requests and I tried using WinInet for POST requests and it didn't work

Comment: Well, I've used the MFC Wininet classes CHttpConnection and CHttpFile to make POST requests, can you provide a failing code? With that it would be easier to understand what are you doing wrong.

Comment: I edited the question and the link to the example is there, it was another question on SO but it doesn't work.

Comment: @David, well reading the link gives me the same conclusion as mentioned in the comments - that scenario will not work since you can't get a POST content from one request in a totally different GET request. Can you describe the scenario what are you trying to do? Upload a file? Just make a plain POST? If you are trying to upload something make the php or whatever is on the other end save it somewhere and verify it. If it is just a plain request, a 200 OK response should be sufficient. Also you can verify the actual post data with Wireshark.

Comment: I am trying to simulate a POST request for a user login. So the form should be filled with parameters posted by the application and log in from the application.

Comment: So when you run the example, what happens? What HTTP status does the server return? The easiest way would be to take Wireshark and to compare a web login with a login done by your code and understand if there are any differences.

Comment: Haven't checked with Wireshark yet but using InternetReadFile, nothing is read.

Comment: Well, if the HTTP response has no content (e.g it is just a 200 OK or a redirect) you will have nothing to read. After you have done the `HttpSendRequest` do a `HttpQueryInfo` with `HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE` and `HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH`. If it is 200 and the content length is 0 it is normal that you don't have any output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61032/discussion-between-david-and-rudolfs-bundulis).

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28324147/4260691) example should help you out and if you are interested in WinInet example you can look in [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165298).

Further more, a quote regarding WinInet from MSDN:

> Note  WinINet does not support server implementations. In addition, it should not be used from a service. For server implementations or services use Microsoft Windows HTTP Services (WinHTTP).

Which is a good advice.